# jQuery DOM append elements - wrong acess them with each loop

Tags: jquery, append

If you'll run the code and then remove elements and then add more (by clicking on the buttons), and then click the sum button - It will not show any results. But if I stay with 2 inputs it works great. What Should I do to make it possible to add more inputs and then make the function work well?
you can see the results in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofek3103/9u5e1r1t/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Simple math between 2 numbers </title>
    <style>
    input {
        margin: 5vw;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var num1, num2, result;
        $("#addInput").click(function() {
            var newId = $('input').length;
            if ( newId < 8) { //Up to 8 inputs
                newId++;
                $("<input type='number' id='number+newId+'/>").appendTo(".inputs");
            }
        });
        $("#removeInput").click(function() {
            var total = $('input').length;
            if ( total > 2) { //At least 2 inputs
                $('input:last-child').remove();
            }
        });
        $("#sum").click(function() {
            var $counter = 0;
            var numbers = {};
            var length = $('input').length;
            var result = 0;
            $('input').each(function(){
               $counter += 1;
               numbers[$counter] = parseInt($('#' + 'number' + $counter ).val());
               result += numbers[$counter];
            });
            $('#result').html(result);
        });
        $("#howMuch").click(function() {
            var total = $('input').length;
            $('#result').html(total);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="number" id="number1" />
        <input type="number" id="number2" />
        <input type="number" id="number3" />
        <input type="number" id="number4" />
        <input type="number" id="number5" />
        <input type="number" id="number6" />
        <input type="number" id="number7" />
        <input type="number" id="number8" />
    </div>
    <button id="addInput"> Add </button>
    <button id="removeInput"> Remove </button> <br />
    <button id="sum"> sum </button>
    <button id="sum"> sub </button>
    <button id="sum"> mul </button>
    <button id="sum"> div </button> <br />
    <button id="howMuch"> How much? </button>
    <p id="result"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$("<input type='number' id='number+newId+'/>").appendTo(".inputs");
```

is the source of the bug, your quotes are misplaced, which produces invalid html.
Fix it like so:

```
$('<input type="number" id="number'+newId+'"/>').appendTo(".inputs");
```

And it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your sum, the problem is you really weirdly try to access value of input when you can just use 'this' in each loop, like that:

```
$("#sum").click(function() {
            var $counter = 0;
            var numbers = {};
            var length = $('input').length;
            var result = 0;
            $('input').each(function(){
                if($(this).val()!=''){
                result += parseInt($(this).val());
              }
            });
            $('#result').html(result);
        });
```